# How to implement JSP to support Multi-Languages (Like Portuguese, Russian )

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

I need to localize a set of JSP pages for languages like Russian and Portuguese in a **Spring** based project.

What I tried was, use **EL** and **JSTL**. But both of them are not supporting above languages. (Displaying disoriented characters-symbols )

JSP snippet (for both EL and JSTL)

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/spring" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/c" prefix="c" %>

<h1><c:out value="${reportName}"/></h1>
<h2>"${reportName}"</h2>
```

Update:
 As example reportName variable is dynamically changing according to the logic in back-end. If we get some values like labels from property files then it's working fine. Only problem is with the dynamic variables passed to the JSP from back-end.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `<fmt:message>` tags to use localization.

`<fmt:message>` tag is used to map the key from the key-value paired mapped localized message and returns the value by replacing the key to the respective value.

The documentation related to it is as under 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/message.html
*Example:*

Taglib imports :

```
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
```

Then you can use in the code :

```
<fmt:setBundle basename="portugeseLang" var="lang"/>
<fmt:setLocale value="hi_port"/>

<fmt:message key="Name" bundle="${lang}"/>
```

Here in the setLocale field you specify the locale.

You can specify the portugese language counter parts in the `portugeseLang.properties` file. You can go through the [J2EE tutorial on internationalization](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakw.html)

Comment: Thanks Aura. This is not related to getting values from specific property file. firstName is a variable passing from back-end. (Not from property files). As example this may be "reportName" and this variable is dynamically changing according to the logic in back-end. If we get some values like labels from property files then it's working fine. Only problem is with the dynamic variables passed to the JSP from back-end. I will update the problem.

Comment: @MalindaMax you need javascript AJAX to communicate back the current user location or ip or timezone ... anyone of these.. this javascript should run first when the page loads... then your java programming logic should change the locale based on the value passed in Ajax call.. and then store the required locale name in session or request parameters and then send it to the web page.